# Refreshing data grid wpf. ItemsSource and Items.Refresh() not working

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

I have simple application and I import data from excel file to data grid. Here is code:

```
private void InitializeDataGridView()
    {
        //Open the Excel file using ClosedXML.
        using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(ExcelFile.ExcelFilePath))
        {
            //Read the first Sheet from Excel file.
            IXLWorksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheet(1);

            //Create a new DataTable.
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            //Loop through the Worksheet rows.
            bool firstRow = true;
            foreach (IXLRow row in workSheet.Rows())
            {
                //Use the first row to add columns to DataTable.
                if (firstRow)
                {
                    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                    }
                    firstRow = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Add rows to DataTable.
                    dt.Rows.Add();
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                    {
                        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell.Value.ToString();
                        i++;
                    }
                }

                dtGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            }
        }
    }
```

It works fine. But I want to add some data. Im using this code:

```
public static void AddData(DateTime date, int time, string title, string description)
    {
        // Opening excel file        
        using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(ExcelFile.ExcelFilePath))
        {              
            IXLWorksheet worksheet = workBook.Worksheet("Progress"); // Trying to get the Progress worksheet
            // Getting table from DataTable
            var dataTable = GetTable(date, time, title, description);
            // Searching for last used row and first used column
            var lastRowUsed = worksheet.LastRowUsed().RowNumber();
            var firstColumnUsed = worksheet.FirstColumnUsed().ColumnNumber();
            // Insterting data               
            worksheet.Cell(lastRowUsed + 1, firstColumnUsed).InsertData(dataTable.AsEnumerable());

            // Adjusting content to fit
            worksheet.Columns().AdjustToContents();
            // Saving excel file
            workBook.Save();
        }

    }

    public static DataTable GetTable(DateTime date, int time, string title, string description)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Data", typeof(DateTime));
        table.Columns.Add("Czas(minuty)", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Tytuł", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Opis", typeof(string));

        table.Rows.Add(date, time, title, description);
        return table;
    }
```

And it's work fine. I have problem with my data grid. Its not updating after I add something to the excel file.

I tried to do something like that:

```
dtGrid.ItemsSource = null;
InitializeDataGridView();
```

It wasnt working. I used also `dtGrid.Items.Refresh();`, it wasnt working.
How can I refresh my data grid after adding data to excel file?

Comment: Have you checked that after your edit your excel process is definitely closing i.e. you cannot see any excel processes running in task manager? If your file is still open then re-initialising your grid will probably not work

Comment: Yes my excel file is definitely closing. Right after Initialize and right after adding some data to it.

Comment: Is the "Progress" sheet the same as `WorkSheet(1)`?

Comment: Yeah since I'm creating the excel file from script too. I think I found how to do it. By data binding.

Answer (score 0):

InitializeDataGridView() has dataGrid.ItemsSource referencing a dataTable dt.DefaultView.

I don't see the same datatable being used in adding new data. If you create new dataTable and add data to it, It needs to be reconnected as new reference of ItemsSource.

I would suggest rather use same ItemsSource throughout the session displaying the dataGrid.